# How can I identify which dynamically added picturebox is currently selected during mouseenter

Tags: vb.net

I dynamically created 5 Picture Box and added Events MouseEnter and MouseLeave, the problem is that when I hover the cursor on one of the picture box, the other will also trigger the event

```
Private Sub Form_TEST_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim ImgSelect As PictureBox
    Dim x As Integer = 1

    While Not x = 5

        ImgSelect = New PictureBox
        ImgSelect.Name = "image0" & x.ToString
        ImgSelect.BackColor = Color.Black
        ImgSelect.Size = New Size(203, 312)
        ImgSelect.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        ImgSelect.Visible = True
        ImgSelect.BringToFront()
        ImgSelect.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage

        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ImgSelect)

        x += 1

        AddHandler ImgSelect.MouseEnter, AddressOf ImgSelect_MouseEnter
        AddHandler ImgSelect.MouseLeave, AddressOf ImgSelect_MouseLeave

    End While

End Sub
```

Comment: give me code for moseneter & leave event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mouse enter event handler, you can get UI control that trigger the event from `sender` parameter :

```
Private Sub ImgSelect_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim CurrentImage As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    ......
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

**you have create one event for the all control add in flow layout panel**
 **this statement bound event on imgselecet and you have one control img select tha's why fir event on all picture box...**

```
 AddHandler ImgSelect.MouseEnter, AddressOf ImgSelect_MouseEnter
    AddHandler ImgSelect.MouseLeave, AddressOf ImgSelect_MouseLeave
```

OR WRITE THIS STATEMENT IN GLOBAL LEVEL AND REMOVE HANDLER

```
 Dim WithEvents ImgSelect As New PictureBox
```

Comment: when you have declare a control with withevent then all event are added when automatically. like other control..